# Erlang: простенький pubsub для сообщений между процессами — приемлем ли мой подход?

Tags: erlang

Захотелось получить в Erlang'е pubsub — процессы могут «подписываться» у некоторого «хаба» и дальше получать копии сообщений, которые получает этот хаб.

Я знаю про `gen_event`, но это мне не подходит — там события обрабатываются в одном процессе event manager'а, а я хочу, чтобы все подписчики были в своих, независимых процессах. Вдобавок к этому я не очень врубился в то, как заставить супервайзоры работать с обработчиками у `gen_event`, а факт того, что обработчики могут падать и их надо перезапускать — однозначен.

В гугле все, увы, забито результатами про Ejabberd и RabbitMQ. Хорошие вещи, но к сути моего вопроса никак не относящиеся — мне, по крайней мере, в обозримом будущем, не потребуется масштабируемое решение с внешним pubsub-сервером.

У меня возникла мысль, что pubsub довольно неплохо накладывается на дерево супервайзоров — достаточно супервайзора научить пересылать вниз по дереву сообщения. Собственно, я набросал вот такой behavior:

```
-module(dispatcher).
-extends(supervisor).
-export([notify/2, start_link/2, start_link/3, handle_cast/2]).

start_link(Mod, Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(dispatcher, {self, Mod, Args}, []).

start_link(SupName, Mod, Args) ->
    gen_server:start_link(SupName, dispatcher, {SupName, Mod, Args}, []).

notify(Dispatcher, Message) ->
    gen_server:cast(Dispatcher, {message, Message}).

handle_cast({message, Message}, State) ->
    {reply, Children, State} = supervisor:handle_call(which_children, dummy, State),
    Pids = lists:filter(fun(Pid) -> is_pid(Pid) end,
                 lists:map(fun({_Id, Child, _Type, _Modules}) -> Child end,
                           Children)),
    [gen_server:cast(Pid, Message) || Pid <- Pids],
    {noreply, State}.
```

И, пусть, вроде бы, все работает как положено — сообщения рассылаются, дети перезапускаются, я не уверен что это была хорошая идея. По крайней мере, я не уверен что до конца правильно понимаю как устроены супервайзоры в OTP, и что я все правильно реализовал.

Покритикуйте, пожалуйста, подход или предложите какую-нибудь альтернативу?

Comment: Репликатор идеально ложится на `gen_server` — в состоянии таскает список подписчиков, по `handle_cast/2` рассылает им копии, все как по учебнику, за исключением усложнения дерева супервайзоров. А, как я понимаю, смотря на state супервайзора — он тоже, все что делает — таскает список детей, линкуется и по `handle_info/2` да ждет сбоев (`{'EXIT', ...}`). Исходя из этого и решил накрутиться на supervisor. Только в гугле на "extending erlang behavior" ценного — аж целый один пост на SO, где предлагают проксировать руками, говоря что behavior'ы плохо расширяются. А у меня как-то работает — странно